# postgres regex international phone code matching

Tags: sql, regex, postgresql

when i insert the code below

```
select (select i.billsec from isp_cdr i) * 
       (select l.user_rate from lcr l ) as nibble_total_billed
where i.destination_number !~'1548749' 
and i.destination_number ~'^(?:[0-7] ?){6,14}[0-9]$' = l.digits;
```

I get this error

> ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "i"
>   LINE 2: where i.destination_number !~'1548749'

isp_cdr table:

```
destination_number
nibble_total_billed
caller_id
billsec
```

lcr table:

```
user_rate
digits
```

digits is phone codes
destination_number is the phone number that user call out

The purpose of this query is to calculate the bill check with the country code (digits) then use the user_rate to multiply the billsec update to nibble_total_billed

sample data

isp_cdr tables

```
destination_number           billsec
60161234587                    50 
60134812315                   127 
60147123512                    98
```

lcr table

```
digits             user_rate
601                   0.15 
4672                  1.6
61891010              1.69
```

Comment: sorry for the messy i don't know how to put in table form i use dash to separate each data

Comment: I don't understand how those two tables are linked? Is `digits` assumed to be the prefix of `destination_number`? So in your example all rows from `isp_cdr` would relate to the row with `(601, 0.15)` in the `lcr` table?

Comment: I just list down the tables attributes that required to use in the this query, i will put in others attributes for you to see thanks for reply

Comment: Just asking with the information above is it possible to do the query? because there are too many links tables is hard to list all of them out.
The condition is to check use the 'destination_number' which is not match to 1548749 then check the 'digits' in 'lcr' use the 'user_rate' of digits multiply with 'billsec' then update to 'nibble_total_billed' 
thanks again !

Answer (score 0):

It's unclear to me what you want to achieve here.

To answer the immediate question why you get the error.

Your statement essentially looks like this:

```
select (..) * (...) as nibble_total_billed
-- you are missing a FROM after the SELECT
where i.destination_number !~'1548749' 
  and i.destination_number ~'^(?:[0-7] ?){6,14}[0-9]$' = l.digits;
```

---

It *seems* you are looking for a join between the two tables:

```
select i.billsec * l.user_rate as nibble_total_billed
from isp_cdr i
  join l.user_rate from l on i.destination_number = l.digits
where i.destination_number !~ '1548749' 
  and i.destination_number ~'^(?:[0-7] ?){6,14}[0-9]$'
```

Given the (invalid) condition `i.destination_number ~'^(?:[0-7] ?){6,14}[0-9]$' = l.digits` it seems you want to "cleanup" the `destination_number` somehow before comparing that to the column `digits` but as you have not shown any sample data it's impossible to answer that part of the question.

Comment: i will at some sample table data in

Comment: isp_cdr tables
destination number                                billsec
               60161234587                           50
               60134812315                           127
               60147123512                            98
lcr table
digits                               user_rate
601                                         0.15
4672                                       1.6